# No Response for Developer Submission

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I submitted a new request for permissions approval for my app more than a week ago. Unfortunately I haven't heard back from Instagram since. Does anyone here have a way of getting in touch with them so I can ask what the hold up is?

Comment: They don't have a contact address on their website?

Comment: Unfortunately they don't or I couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, that I am aware of, to contact Instagram for Developers. I've looked rather extensively. They contact you exclusively.

If they haven't rejected your request yet, then have patience. It can take a while due to the high volume of requests and the level of effort that they put into each review. My first request took over two weeks. I also had a request that took less than a week about 4 months ago.

Since Instagress just shut down, I feel like a lot of people are putting in requests right now. I wouldn't get concerned until you haven't heard back for more than a month. If that's the case, there's probably something wrong with your request.

I highly recommend you review all the documentation about putting in requests and only include the minimum amount of information (don't be verbose). Also, make sure you save the answers you submitted to a word document or something before submitting because if your request is rejected, you won't get any 
information about why and Instagram does not let you see what you submitted. After waiting a long 2+ weeks and getting rejected, I had to remember exactly what I submitted to try and understand why I was rejected. I try to quote the language used in the use cases on the [Permission Review](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/) document in my answers and use very concise answers. I let the video do the talking (metaphorically speaking, my videos used no audio and I would recommend no including audio in your video either). I have a feeling that long answers to the questions are more likely to be rejected. They're really looking to make sure you fit a use case then they're looking for any reason to reject you.

Lastly, if it's taking this long, then I think it's safe to say that you're going to get rejected. In my experience, when my requests were accepted, it was pretty quick, when they were rejected, it took longer. Idk if this is a fact, I'm a sample size of 1 person and I've made 4 requests (2 rejected, 2 accepted). Good luck bro! If you want some help, DM me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mike. The only thing my app uses is the ability to log in to my website using Instagram as an identity provider. Thus my answers to their questions are very short, the video has no audio and demonstrates the flow of signing up using Instagram only. In my opinion this is as simple and straight forward as it gets! However, I guess I'll just have to keep waiting for now.